# Поиск в строке по определенному алгоритму

Tags: php, строки, поиск

Добрый день!
Помогите, пожалуйста, решить следующий вопрос:
Необходимо на php написать скрипт, у нас есть текст, который мы вводим с клавиатуры и есть некий набор правил с которым введенный текст нужно сравнивать. Например строка "send text to myemail@.ru" . Эту строку сравниваем с символом @ - в строке он имеется, находим его позицию. Потом, от этой позиции идем вправо до первого пробела и влево. Находим позиции этих пробелов. И вырезаем текст таким образом с позиции левого пробела до позиции правого. При учете, что у нас может быть у слова, в котором мы нашли совпадение с нашим символом, пробел слева, пробел справа, пробелы слева и справа, вообще не быть пробелов.

```
<?php 
$str1=""; $strfind = "";
 foreach($data as $key=>$value) {
  $pos = strpos($pole, $key);  
  if($pos ===false){ 
  echo "указанных запрещенных слов в тексте не найдено";
 $str1=$str1.$value; 
$strfind=$strfind.$key; 
  }else{
   $pos_probela_1 = strpos($pole, " ", ($pos+1));
   $pos_probela_2 = strpos($pole, " ", -strlen($pole));
//тут теперь могут быть как раз проблемы с условиями(не могу догадаться как их поставить)
 if($pos_probela_1 !== false && $pos_probela_2 !== false){
  $before = substr($pole, $pos+1, $pos_probela_1-$pos);
  $after = substr($pole, $pos_probela_2+1, ($pos-$pos_probela_2-1));
  $res = $after.$key.$before;
 }
 if($pos_probela_1 === false){
  $before = substr($pole, $pos_probela_2+1, $pos-$pos_probela_2);
  $after = substr($pole, $pos+1, strlen($pole)-$pos);
  $res = $before.$key.$after;
  }else{
//это если вообще пробелы в строке не обнаружились, но при этом нашло указанную комбинацию символов, то мы вырезаем полностью все слово
 $res = substr($pole, 0, strlen($pole));
        }
    echo "нашли слово ".$res."<hr>";
    echo "длинна слова ".strlen($pole);
    if($pos_probela_1){
        echo "<br>первый пробел".$pos_probela_1.'<br>';
    }

    if($pos_probela_2){
        echo "<br>второй".$pos_probela_2.'<br>';
        }
        $str1 =$str1.$value; $strfind=$strfind.$key;
?>
```

Проблема с условиями, а именно - где по логике нет пробелов, например так "myemail@mail.ru" - если такая строка, то мы вырезаем ее полностью. Если же строка такая "наш эмейл -  myemail@.ru" - тут у нас слева от найденного слова есть пробел. И по коду который я написал у меня этот пробел попадает в условия где вообще нет пробелов. Может чтото там неправильно написал.
Вообщем прошу помощи как реализовать это дело чтоб оно работало если у нас есть пробел слева от найденного слова или справа, или вообще нету пробелов.

Comment: вам нужно получить в результат адрес электронной почты?

Comment: Мне нужно получить любое слово - в зависимости от того что будут искать, и если это найдется, то должно вытягиваться. Это может быть эмейл, потом ссылка, потом часть слова, потом любой символ ну и регулярное выражение. Вообщем 5 разновидностей правил. Сейчас бы хоть с одним разобраться.

Comment: вы были тут сорок минут назад, и не ответили - мой вариант подходит для вашей задачи? Вы его пробовали? Или его удалить?

Comment: А что делать если я напишу текст вообще без пробелов? Как искать будете?

Comment: если нет пробелов, но есть искомый шаблон в строке - то берем всю строку. Пробелы это как главный распределитель - в зависимости от их количества мы меняем логику нашего скрипта.

Comment: @Vitaliy D, вы игнорируете мой вопрос?

Comment: я написал че надо получить. Ваша метода не подходит. спасибо. По вашему я сам знаю как решить. Мне надо так как у меня написано ну или частично хотя бы.

Answer (score 0):

Так нельзя?

```
$text = 'наш эмейл - myemail@.ru';
preg_match('/(?:\s|^)(\S*?@.*?)(?:\s|$)/', $text, $matches);
var_dump($matches[1]);
```

[Пример](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/33a93caf2a77c97ba75bc803628861098ab765a5)

Comment: Могу написать полный текст условия. Может я чето не так понял. Вообщем текст:Реализовать такие типы проверок:
1) Проверка наличия запрещенных слов: SiteAnalyst,SiteAdmin,
Administration. Список запрещенных слов может изменяться с некоторой периодичностью вручную.
2) Проверка по набору регулярных выражений:
'(f+a+c+e+b+[o0]+[o0]+k+)'
'(f+(a+)?.{1,2}c+e+b+.{1,2}o+k+)'
'(f+.{1,3}b+o+[kc]+)'
Список регулярных выражений может изменяться с некоторой периодичностью вручную.
3) Проверка наличия email в тексте
4) Проверка наличия ссылок на веб ресурсы в тексте.